# image upload and CreateView based view

Tags: django, image-upload, django-class-based-views

I want to be able to upload an image file using CreateView and a ModelForm but I can't get it working - it seems the form doesn't bind any file data after choosing a file. Here's the current content of the view:

```
class AddContentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Media


class AddContentView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'simple_admin/add_content.html'
    form_class = AddContentForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return u'/opettajat/subcategory/{0}/{1}/'.format(self.kwargs['subcat_name'].decode('utf-8'), self.kwargs['subcat_id'].decode('utf-8'))


    def form_valid(self, form):
        isvalid = super(AddContentView, self).form_valid(form)
        s = Subcategory.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['subcat_id'].encode('utf-8'))
        if self.request.POST.get('image'):
            image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            title = form.cleaned_data['art_title'].encode('utf-8')
            year_of_creation = form.cleaned_data['year_of_creation']
            m = Media.objects.get_or_create(image=image, art_title=title, year_of_creation=year_of_creation)[0]
            s.media.add(m)
            s.save()
       return isvalid

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AddContentView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['subcategory_name'] = self.kwargs['subcat_name'].encode('utf-8')
        context['subcategory_id'] = self.kwargs['subcat_id'].encode('utf-8')
        return context

     @method_decorator(login_required)
     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AddContentView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Can anyone help? An simple example of class based image upload view would be appreciated.

Answer (score 19):

Uploaded files are stored in `request.FILES`, not in `request.POST`. And don't forget to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` tag.

And I think `form_valid` method is for validation, not for data saving, isn't it?

Comment: I've have enctype="multipart/form-data" in my <form> (googled that one out just moment's ago) but thank you for the reminder :) self.request.POST.get('image') only checks if the forms image field was used. The big problem problem is that self.request.FILES doesn't contain anything when submitting the form so I can't do anything with it at all.

Comment: @boromil Are files sent to the server? (check it with FireBug)

Comment: ah sorry - didn't notice the part about firebug - where in firebug can i find the info about sending files - I'm not to familiar with it.
`<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/opettajat/add/content/{{ subcategory_name }}/{{ subcategory_id }}/" method="post" style="float: none;">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_django_admin }}
            <input type="submit" value="Add Content"/>
        </form>`

Comment: @boromil On Network tab you can examine headers of your post request. If the file isn't sent, something is wrong with html layout of your form.

Comment: you were right - an error in the template file - it now uploads correctly - now I only need to fix some other stuff. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @DrTyrsa to answer your question, `form_valid` is for saving. Validation is done by `is_valid`. ;)

Comment: @Dionys I was speaking about the method of CBV, not form's: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid

Comment: just adding enctype="multipart/form-data" to my form helped get things working for me, thanks